# Redirect html link based on time

Tags: html, url, redirect, time

So I have a website which has a link to a form - within the same domain name. However I only want the form to be accessible during specific times of the day i.e. 2.30pm-4pm and 8.30pm-12am. Outside of these hours, it should automatically redirect to another page if the link to that page is clicked. I.e. it should divert whenever that page is being accessed out of hours if that makes sense.

Any ideas as to how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done with pure HTML as HTML is static. You could do this in a variety of languages depending on what your server is running.

A Javascript solution could work, but the client could get around it if Javascript were to be disabled so I would recommend a server sided solution (PHP, Node.js, PERL, whatever you use etc.)

Comment: So how would I go about doing this in php - the server I'm using supports it